# Unity - audio taking up over half the memory? Compression?

Tags: c#, ios, audio, unity-game-engine

Ok, I am new to audio with unity but despite reading all the Unity posts regarding audio adding 2 short .wav clips (I heard wav was smaller than mp3) to my app has added over 200mb. If this is the case, I will not be able to incorporate sound.

I have checked override iOS as that is how to compress images, but I don't know if my settings are compressing accurately.
Here is my settings right now:

[image]

Why are my audio files taking up so much space? How can I reduce this size?

Comment: "I heard wav was smaller than mp3" This is absolutely false. wav is uncompressed audio and is typically around 10 to 15 times larger than mp3 for the same length audio. [Here's a chart](http://dsd-guide.com/size-comparison-chart-various-formats-dsd-wav-flac-mp3#.WQ5OIsa1tjE) that shows some different sizes for various audio formats you can reference.

Comment: Ok I changed to mp3 and even still its adding about 200mb. I don't understand why this is

Comment: Try to lower the quality property.

Answer (score 0):

Set "Load Type" to "compressed in memory" and you can reduce the quality to about 70%. And enable "Force To Mono".